# How to add different icons to dynamic table depending on the data that I am receiving?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dynamic-data, dynamic-tables

I have an Angular Material dynamic table. How can I add different
colors or icons depending on the data that I am receiving, so that not every row is affected to have the color or icon?
 you can see every row has the button but I don't want to show that on every row.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjjpgq?file=src%2Fapp%2FresuseableComponent%2Fdata-table.component.html)

Comment: For separating the StackBlitz demo, please move it on a separate line, and also show some indicative code in the question body as well

Answer (score 0):

You can add class on your tr tag by condition

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [class.active]="row.isActive"></tr>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hle7vp

Comment: this is not a dynamic table